# PHP class scope: class not seen in included files

Tags: php

I have a class...

```
class myclass {}
$myclass = new myclass();
$myclass->frigin = 'awesome';
```

Later on in a *different* PHP file I have some includes...

```
include('hippie_deflectors.php');
```

However the PHP in that includes does not see `$myclass` at all.

What is the simplest way to make PHP obey?

---

This file...
`.com/[module]/requested_page.php`

...has two includes which filter down the following top-to-bottom...

**Includes set 1**

---

`.com/system/header.php`

`.com/system/header_classes.php` [`$myclass` is defined here]

**Includes set 2**

---

`.com/[module]/index_get.php`

`.com/system/template_1.php`

`.com/system/includes_js.php`

`.com/system/scripts/onload.js` [`$myclass` undefined here]

Comment: lol hippie deflectors. What do you mean `does not see`? If you instantiate an myclass object, do you get an error?

Comment: Can you post the exact error and maybe the code for hippie_deflectors.php  ?  if it's a class in there trying to see $myclass, it needs to be made global.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can properly diagnose this.

Comment: The include is NOT defined in the same PHP file as the class.

Comment: That is how php works. If you not instantiate your class, it will obvious not come to live! `$myclass = new myclass();`

Comment: @JvdBerg I was missing a line that exists in my code, edited post.

Comment: I have several hundred files with classes that get included, you must do something wrong in the include. Show the code where you want to use `$myclass`

Comment: You are using `$myclass` in a javascript file?

Comment: @JvdBerg You can execute PHP in different files just fine, yes. Everything works fine except PHP doesn't see the class.

Comment: Can you show the code in onload.js where $myclass is used?

Comment: `echo $myclass->frigin;`

Comment: Why not show a little more code of `onload.js`?

Comment: There is nothing more relevant in that file, all I want to do is echo a class variable. Somehow the scope stops at this point. In other cases I pass `$myclass` as a parameter however there are no functions I'm executing in onload.js so I have no way to sneak the class to this file.

Comment: What kind of code is in `onload.js`? the extension suggests it is javascript?

Comment: @JvdBerg:Maybe I should do the same thing you did and get all worked up about how extended comments conversation should be moved to chat?

Comment: I have no problem with moving to the chat if John wants help

Comment: @JvdBerg I'm there now, got a phone call, free now.

Comment: @JvdBerg: Neither do I, just telling you that when you go around telling others how their answer is "vague" and they are "rushing" and stuff - remember that you do similar things in other aspects. Just a gentle reminder next time you want to rush on to criticize someone. Now all the best helping him.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit to comprehend. But this will work:

File: File1.php

```
class myclass {}
$myclass->frigin = 'awesome';
include('hippie_deflectors.php');
```

File: hippie_deflectors.php

```
include('different_file.php');
```

File: different_file.php

```
var_dump($myclass);
```

will print:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["frigin"]=> string(7) "awesome" }
```

Is this the setup you are having?

Comment: The PHP includes in NOT in the same PHP file as where the class is declared.

Comment: The includes is by the way you've posted it in the same chunk of code as the class. Think of the PHP class file and the PHP file with the includes as being included by higher PHP files (includes->included-class, includes-[dif directory]->included-PHP-file).

Comment: -1 How can this code work without instantiating the class? your print gives a instance of `stdClass` while the class is a type of `myclass`!

Comment: @JvdBerg: well technically, because `$myclass->frigin = 'awesome';` creates an object of `StdClass`. I am sure the OP knows that he needs to call constructor. He is giving semi-pseudo code in question and so am I. So if you cannot come down to our level, at least stay out instead of doing your personal Eureka moment and giving -1s as if you got an epiphany!! Had you seen how vague the initial question was? I initiated a dialogue and got the OP to add more info about the question - at some point it might come out that he did not instantiate maybe? But I hate trigger-fingered comment spewers!

Comment: Updated my post, check it out.

Comment: Your 'answer' is not a answer. As long as it is vague, place a comment and ask for information. I hate people who provide 'answers' as a race to the clock

Comment: @JvdBerg: Oh please grow up...I do not find it easy to post in more than enough lines into "comments" just to satisfy the whims of folks like you, where as it is more legible and easier to paste it into answers so that the OP understands - and then take it from there. We are trying to solve a problem, not make it more difficult just because "purists" want to draw the line over what is vague and so constitutes a comment. And I was not "racing" to answer the OP. In fact look at my "answer" - it ends with a question for crying out loud - I was only trying to help. Still cant stand the purists

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake which hopefully someone else will learn from. While I have had issues of scope (a PHP file including another and then only being able to access a class by passing it as a parameter to a function) what I ended up realizing was that the JavaScript file was being output as a string, not as an includes! That means that the JavaScript file would make the browser make a second request of which only that file would be parsed by PHP.

Visually...

- Client Request [JavaScript file output in string for script element]
- Client receives page result.
- Client requests script file.
- Script file parsed by PHP on ***second/separate request***.

Thankfully since I program things to be highly modular I was able to declare the class, create a new copy of it and then include a modular PHP file that doesn't include the entire class but a smaller though more universal chunk of variables that I needed.

This does not resolve the separate though related issue where classes are only accessible in X number of includes before you have to pass them as parameters to functions.